# can't get to finish installing tesseract following their tutorial

Tags: c#, tesseract

Trying to create a code that helps me get a passeport scan so i'm following the tesseract download and insrall in this link https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#windows.
i did all of the above but when it comes to this 
cd tesseract
cppan
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
i just get in the tesseract directory and can't open cppan , it says No spec file found
please help !

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a tesseract error, it is a cppan error.
Make sure the cppan installation went well, if needed go here https://github.com/cppan/cppan
and install the latest version yourself.

The last option you might consider is creating the spec file yourself.

Make sure you understand the stage 4 is comprised of 4 different commands.

Comment: how do i procced after downloading cppan-master?

Comment: You need to install it properly, follow section 2 from your tutorial, then just run 'cppan' from tesseract folder

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this in Cygwin?  I did, and got the same error but it worked fine in a cmd command window.  The install script seems to insist on using Windows filesystem references, because I found the failed script had created a subdirectory under my tesseract directory named "C:".

The cppan instructions should have added:  "In a cmd window, navigate to the tesseract root directory.  Either add cppan to your system PATH variable, or give the correct directory path to cppan.exe in the following command..."

(I think it will work fine in a command shell like cmder too, as long as it recognizes the Windows directory syntax.)

(I don't think cppan needs to remain in your system PATH permanently unless you plan to use it for other things.)